# Run train op multiple times in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have some fairly large batch sizes on which I'd like to take multiple gradient steps. While I could easily do this with a python for loop, I imagine that there might be a more efficient method that doesn't involve transferring the data to gpu on each iteration. I've tried putting the train op in the fetch list multiple times, but I'm not sure that it's actually being run more than once (the runtime is exactly the same).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have variable-sized batch then variable is a bad fit for saving it, and you could instead persist this data between `run` calls using peristent tensors. Here's a toy example

```py
t = tf.int32
params = tf.Variable(tf.ones_initializer((), dtype=dt))
data_batches = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

# op that uploads data to TF and saves it as a persistent Tensor
data_saver_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dt)
tensor_handle_op = tf.get_session_handle(data_saver_placeholder)

data_placeholder, data = tf.get_session_tensor(dt)
train_op = tf.assign_add(params, tf.reduce_prod(data)) 
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

for batch in data_batches:
    # upload tensor to TF runtime and save its handle
    tensor_handle = sess.run(tensor_handle_op, feed_dict={data_saver_placeholder: batch})
    # run train op several times reusing same data
    for i in range(3):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={data_placeholder: tensor_handle.handle})


assert sess.run(params) == 382
```

Comment: I was using this solution for a while, but it no longer works because of a change in the `get_session_tensor` API - a handle is now required in addition to a dtype.

Comment: If you look at source, the handle is only used to determine device of the tensor. So if you are using CPU, you could create a dummy handle on the CPU and reuse that

Comment: Thanks, Yaroslav, but I am confused about two things.  First, shouldn't the dummy handle be on the GPU not the CPU since the purpose is to avoid multiple transfers of a large batch from CPU to GPU?  Second, why don't we need to call `delete_session_tensor` to free the memory?

Comment: what is dt in your example?

Answer (score 2):

If you do `sess.run([myop,myop])` that'll only run `myop` once.

If you want to run the op, but not fetch its results to Python runtime you could use a control dependency. A simple way to do this is with a `group` op, ie

```
sess.run(tf.group(myop))
sess.run(tf.group(myop))
```

If your graph is large you may get an extra overhead by constructing `group` op between run calls (maybe 10-100ms for >10k node graph), so you could construct it ahead of time

```
myop_nooutput = tf.group(myop)
sess.run(myop_nooutput)
sess.run(myop_nooutput)
```

Comment: Where is the feed dict in your examples?

Comment: you can pass `feed_dict` to sess.run as an extra argument

Comment: So the feed_dict would be separately passed on each run? (This is what I was hoping to avoid).

Comment: You can avoid multiple feed_dict transfers by putting your data onto GPU first, like in answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596333/tensorflow-store-training-data-on-gpu-memory

Comment: That answer doesn't work for me... I can't store my whole dataset on the gpu and just slice it to get my batches.

Comment: You can save your contents of your "feed_dict" into a variable on GPU once using variable and `assign` from a placeholder, and then run `sess.run` several times where the op in question takes input from the variable rather than placeholder

Comment: Aha, I should have thought of that! Thanks!

Comment: On second thought, this doesn't quite work for me, since my feed tensors have variable (batch) size, but tf Variables must have a fixed size at construction.

Comment: Since your parameters are fixed size, at some point in your train-op your variable-size batch gets turned into fixed size vector, so you can save that in a variable. For instance, if you are using a standard optimizer, you end-up with a gradient, which is fixed size, so you could save that in a variable, and call `apply_gradient` several times

Comment: That would be equivalent to multiplying the learning rate by the number of steps I want to take, which isn't quite what I want. What I want is to take a gradient step, then recompute the gradient with the new parameters (but the same data), take another step, and so on.