# Load multidimensional (numpy) array into GPU memory and slice from it - with Keras?

Tags: python, memory, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37596846/1672565), which explains how one can load a (multidimensional) numpy array as a constant into GPU memory and slice from it (each slice being a potential batch for training) with TensorFlow. I was wondering whether it was possible to do the same with Keras (with TensorFlow backend) and, if yes, how. I may have overlooked it, but I have not seen something like it in the documentation.